# From a docker container how do I see another docker container?

Tags: docker, jira, openldap

Based on:
https://github.com/osixia/docker-phpLDAPadmin

I am running OpenLDAP and phpLDAPadmin containers with:

```
docker run --name ldap-service --hostname ldap-service --detach -p 389:389 -p 636:636 --detach osixia/openldap:1.1.8 
docker run --name phpldapadmin-service --hostname phpldapadmin-service --link ldap-service:ldap-host --env PHPLDAPADMIN_LDAP_HOSTS=ldap-host --detach osixia/phpldapadmin:0.7.1
```

(based on suggestions below I have also tried `-p 689:689` and adjust accordingly in jira but get the same errors).

I also start another container from a JIRA image with:

```
docker run -p 0.0.0.0:8087:8087 -d --name mycontainer jiraimage tail -f/dev/null
```

In my browser on my host machine I can access the phpldapadmin web interface on:

https://172.17.0.3/

and jira on:

http://localhost:8087

Next I try to configure a LDAP directory in JIRA pointing to the running OpenLDAP server with but get the below error:

```
Connection test failed. Response from the server:
ldap-service:636; nested exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: ldap-service:636 [Root exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: ldap-service]
```

[image]

So it seems the JIRA container cannot see the hostname of the OpenLDAP container.

I have also tried: `172.17.0.3` on the jira side but same result.

How do I get the jira container to see the OpenLDAP container?

More info:

```
# docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.09.0-ce
 API version:  1.32
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   afdb6d4
 Built:        Tue Sep 26 22:42:45 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.09.0-ce
 API version:  1.32 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   afdb6d4
 Built:        Tue Sep 26 22:41:24 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

And:

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                           COMMAND                 CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                 NAMES
de167e404cc3        jiraimage                        tail -f /dev/null"     6 seconds ago       Up 4 seconds        0.0.0.0:8087->8087/tcp                                mycontainer
3a4a771037ac        osixia/phpldapadmin:0.7.1       "/container/tool/run"   6 seconds ago       Up 5 seconds        80/tcp, 443/tcp                                       phpldapadmin-service
aa2d78fdcd99        osixia/openldap:1.1.8-001       "/container/tool/run"   7 seconds ago       Up 5 seconds        0.0.0.0:389->389/tcp, 0.0.0.0:636->636/tcp, 636/tcp   ldap-service
```

Based on the below answer regarding creating a user defined network I now have a connection:

[image]

I first create a user defined network with:

```
docker network create --driver bridge sample-network
```

and start my containers with:

```
docker run --network=sample-network --name ldap-service --hostname ldap-service --detach -p 389:389 -p 636:636 --detach osixia/openldap:1.1.8 
docker run --network=sample-network --name phpldapadmin-service --hostname phpldapadmin-service --env PHPLDAPADMIN_LDAP_HOSTS=ldap-host --detach osixia/phpldapadmin:0.7.1
docker run --network=sample-network -p 0.0.0.0:8087:8087 -d --name mycontainer jiraimage tail -f/dev/null
```

I had to remove: `--link ldap-service:ldap-host` from the LDAP container so phpadmin can no longer connect to openldap:

[image]

What do I need to change to re-enable that?

Comment: Which docker version are you using? Also please add the output of `docker ps` to your question

Comment: Isn't the ldap available on port 689 instead of 636? because you did -p 689:689 instead of -p 689:636?

Comment: I have fixed it so the container is using -p 636:636. I also tried to change to -p 689:689 on the container and also change to 689 in jira but I get the same error.

Comment: It seems to me that you did not --link the Jira image to your ldap service. `--link` is a legacy feature as described [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks) so it's better to use user defined networks instead.

Comment: Ok could you be a bit more specific on how to do that based on the above example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply define first a **network** and add your two containers to that network.
See [docker container networking](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/).
(this replaces the [obsolete legacy container links](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/) )

Then you can reference your LDAP using its container IP address.

> Containers connected to the default bridge network can communicate with each other by IP address. Docker does not support automatic service discovery on the default bridge network.

As [BMitch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596285/bmitch) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48487882/from-a-docker-container-how-do-i-see-another-docker-container/48547404?noredirect=1#comment84097159_48547404), you should reference ldap with its service name, not `ldap-host`:

```
--env PHPLDAPADMIN_LDAP_HOSTS=ldap-service
```

Comment: That finally gave me a connection, but I now I have a few issues with the ldap containers, see updated post.

Comment: @u123 Set `PHPLDAPADMIN_LDAP_HOSTS=ldap-service` not `ldap-host`.

Comment: @u123 I have edited my answer accordingly, including BMitch's comment.